# Auto-updating PowerPoint Slides with previous Month and Year

Tags: office365, powerpoint

**Background -**
I have a PowerPoint presentation for a report I need to produce each month, that is reporting on the previous month's data. E.g. when I distribute the presentation in January 2021, it should have a date on each slide (positioning varies per slide), which references 'December 2020'.

**Question -** 
In PowerPoint, is there a way I can have a text box that dynamically displays the previous month and (if applicable) the previous year? E.g., in January 2021, it will show December 2020 etc.

**What I've tried -**
I have tried using the 'Header/Footer' function and 'Date & Time' option in PowerPoint, but alas it doesn't seem to support previous dates.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: This is a dangerous path to go down. What if the January presentation gets opened in March? If you dynamically base the date in the footer on the current date, then that date for the January presentation will show February. Not advisable. It is much easier and much safer to just edit the presentation footer and enter the correct date for that file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this (albeit in a messy way) by creating a formula in an Excel file, then bringing this into PowerPoint as a linked image.